# AngularJS ng-if with angular expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

View:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
....
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

      <p>Current user {{loggedOnUser}}</p>

      <div ng-if="user.name == {{loggedOnUser}}" ng-repeat="user in users">
        <p>Should display</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.loggedOnUser = "xxx"; // for testing purpose
    $scope.users = [
      {
        name : "xxx",
        age: "25"
      },
      {
        name : "yyy",
        age: "26"
      }
    ];
 });
```

How to use ng-if with angularJS expression or is there any other way to achieve this??
I want to show that div if my loggedOnUser is equal to user.name

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need not explicitly give interpolate braces to `loggedInUser`. `$compile` does that for the `ng-if` directive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be

```
ng-if="user.name == loggedOnUser"
```

instead of

```
ng-if="user.name == {{loggedOnUser}}"
```

You can user `filters` if you want to. But I suggest you to not trust on filters in your case. Please see below snippet, it will work in your above scenario.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:name:loggedOnUser">
```

Comment: @PratapA.K You can accept as an answer for further usage

Comment: Sure will do that!! I have one more doubt,

What if $scope of loggedOnUser and users array are different???

Comment: You must be using `service` or `factory` in this case you can reference the literals to that `factory` or `service`.

Answer (score 3):

The condition for ng-if is an angular expression itself.

```
<ANY
    ng-if="expression">
    ...
</ANY>
```

therefore something like:

```
ng-if="someVal"
```

will match for **$scope.someVal** and not against the string "someVal"

so in your case it should be:

```
ng-if="user.name == loggedOnUser"
```